# Частные репозитории Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, репозиторий, обновления, терминал

Необходим список репозиториев для Ubuntu 13.04, желательно отобразить их списком, чтоб можно было сразу в терминал вставить и установить. Дело в том, что мой провайдер Ростелеком блокирует доступ к некоторым ресурсам, например репозиториям Ubuntu.

В [предыдущем своём вопросе](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/7230/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-ubuntu-13-04) я не могу сейчас ничего сделать, ни комментировать, ни принимать ответы, возможно это глюк РутКода, а может и моего провайдера, потому не серчайте, если ответа долго не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот белорусы вряд-ли заблокированы.

```
deb http://ftp.byfly.by/ubuntu/ saucy main deb-src http://ftp.byfly.by/ubuntu/ saucy main
```

а правда что случилось ? какой город и прочее. в 2012 г вроде в Оренбурге такое было.

Comment: Тольятти, хз что случилось там.

Comment: сегодня Яндекс заработал, но репы яндекса пока ещё не работают.

Comment: а можно узнать причины, по которым не используются штатные репозитории?

Comment: @Octogen он же сказал, у него ISP тупит и блочит

Answer (score 2):

Питер. Ростелеком (ADSL). Все работает.В убунте - диспетчер настроек - Программы и обновления - Загрузить с ... . Выбираешь с сервера какой страны грузить.

Comment: Палец вверх от меня, за подсказку, только у меня подругому: "центр приложений/правка/источники приложений/грузить с..."

Comment: Ну у меня Xubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь: http://sivkaburka.blogspot.ru/2008/03/dvd.html очень неплохо описано, как сделать собственный репозиторий на DVD!